# Why are many of the interfaces in the redux-form typings not exported?

Tags: typescript, redux-form

I want to make some custom input fields for redux-form.

So I started off by looking at the [Material UI example](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/material-ui/) in the documentation.

```
const renderTextField = ({input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) =>
    <TextField
        hintText={label}
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...input}
        {...custom}
    />
```

That looks straight forward, so I checked out the [definitely typed type definitions for redux-form](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redux-form/) and found the [interfaces defining what I wanted](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redux-form/lib/Field.d.ts#L66).

```
interface WrappedFieldProps {
    input: WrappedFieldInputProps;
    meta: WrappedFieldMetaProps;
}
```

But they're not exported?

So how do I apply the interface to a `renderField` function, if I can't access the interface?

Am I missing something obvious, or taking the wrong approach?

I don't think the official documentation is wrong, so are the type definitions wrong in not exporting?

One way around this is to have the render function take `props:any`, but that will render the type definitions useless!

```
const renderTextField = (props:any) => {
    const {input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom } = props;

    return (
        <TextField
            hintText={label}
            floatingLabelText={label}
            errorText={touched && error}
            {...input}
            {...custom}
        />
    );
}
```

So not only can I not use the interfaces in my own code, but they wouldn't be used when passing the function to `<Field component={renderTextField} />`.

Comment: `GenericField` and `Field` are exported, and they use `WrappedFieldProps`. Can't you make use of any of those?

Comment: @Arg0n Unfortunately not, I need the typings for the function being passed to `Field`, rather than `Field` itself. However your comment prompted me to investigate some things further and I've now found a solution, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that it is in fact possible to import the interfaces, even though they aren't being exported!

I was using `import * as ReduxForm from "redux-form";` which imported the module under the name `ReduxForm`.

Looking at what was available on `ReduxForm` showed only the exported parts of the module.

However if I use an import that explicitly asks for the non-exported interface `import { WrappedFieldProps } from "redux-form";` then it works, and I can use that interface!

This has confused me a bit, it runs against my understanding how of import/export and modules work. But I'm glad I have a solution.

I now need to go and read up on Typescript imports to figure out if this is a feature, or a bug. (I assume it's a feature).